# Latin Hypercube Sampling (LHS) in R

Tags: r, kriging

I am new to R and would like to generate Latin Hypercube samples (LHS) for three variables within the following limts:

- 1.25 ≤ x1 ≤ 5 ,
- 1.25 ≤ x2 ≤ 5
- 7 ≤ x1 ≤ 25

with total 3*10 = 30 samples.

What is the syntax to be used in Rstudio?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [lhs package documentation for reference](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lhs/versions/1.0.1)

You would need to install the released version of `lhs` from CRAN

```
install.packages("lhs")
```

or via devtools

```
devtools::install_github("bertcarnell/lhs")
```

in your case a example to create a random LHS with 30 samples and 3 variables would be:

```
X <- randomLHS(30, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Whyzar, yes i had installed package lhs !!